# C# Nest ElasticSearch Not able to map "token_chars" to Nest fluentMapping

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I have created below index through ElasticSearch Sense browser plugin, and also created C# Nest Fluent Mapping. I can express everything in Nest except "token_chars" on nGrams filter. I am not getting strongly typed property on C# nest to add "token_chars". Has anybody faced the same problem?

The json and c# settings are listed as below.
    Please help

```
        "analysis": {
           "analyzer": {
              "str_index_analyzer": {
                 "filter": [
                    "lowercase",
                    "substring"
                 ],
                 "tokenizer": "keyword"
              },
           "filter": {
              "substring": {
                 "max_gram": "50",
                 "type": "nGram",
                 "min_gram": "2",
                 "token_chars": [ /*Not able to map */
                    "letter",
                    "digit"
                 ]
              }
           }
```

I am not getting strongly typed property on C# nest to add "token_chars". Is anybody faced the same problem?

```cs
           var result = this._client.CreateIndex("mkfindex1", c => c
           .Analysis(a => a.Analyzers(an => an.Add("str_index_analyzer", new CustomAnalyzer()
            {
                Filter = new string[] { "lowercase", "substring" },
                Tokenizer = "keyword"
            })).TokenFilters(bases => bases.Add("substring", new NgramTokenFilter()
            {
                MaxGram = 50,
                MinGram = 2,

                /*"token_chars": [//Not able to map
                    "letter",
                    "digit"
                 */
             }))));
```

Comment: mind adding a github issue for this? https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-net/issues?direction=desc&sort=updated&state=open

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have run into the same issue. The workaround for this is to not use the Fluent Mapping and just specify your analysis settings directly as Fluent Dictionary entries via the `Settings.Add()` method. Below is an example that should configure your index correctly.

```cs
 var result = this._client.CreateIndex("mkfindex1", c => c
     .Settings.Add("analysis.analyzer", "str_index_analyzer")
     .Settings.add("analysis.analyzer.str_index_analyzer.type", "custom")
     .Settings.add("analysis.analyzer.str_index_analyzer.tokenizer", "keyword")
     .Settings.Add("analysis.analyzer.str_index_analyzer.filter.0", "lowercase")
     .Settings.Add("analysis.analyzer.str_index_analyzer.filter.1", "substring")
     .Settings.add("analysis.filter.substring.type", "nGram")
     .Settings.add("analysis.filter.substring.min_gram", "2")
     .Settings.add("analysis.filter.substring.max_gram", "50")
     .Settings.add("analysis.filter.substring.token_chars.0", "letter")
     .Settings.add("analysis.filter.substring.token_chars.0", "digit")
   );
```

Hope this helps.